# Access file on host

Tags: android, file, silverlight, usb

So here is the deal:

I have one Silverlight 5 application which makes heavy use of internet connection. If there is no internet connection, I can make server calls using long code service over Android device. So if there is no internet connection on computer, I can perform following steps:

1) Save server calls made by Silverlight application in serialiazed format in some file locally on computer.

2) Connect Android device to computer (using USB cable preferably).

3) Run Android application which will access that file on computer, read it's contents and make server calls using long code service.

I know we can access local file system in Silverlight 5 application, so no hurdle in step 1. Step 2 is obvious. But I've no idea regarding how can I access a file on connected computer in Android programmatically to perform step 3. Please help.

Comment: I don't think Android apps can access host computer's file system, but you probably could copy that file to Android device's USB storage through Silverlight application? And then read the file from there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @shoerat. But unfortunately I don't know how to make Silverlight access device's USB storage. :-(